# What type should I use to match FunctionComponent that returns a div?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

interface ChildProps {
  id: string
}

const Child = function (props: ChildProps) {
  return <div {...props} />
}

interface ParentProps {
  node: FunctionComponent<ChildProps> // How can I improve this type to match function components that return a div?
}

const Parent = function (props: ParentProps) {
  const Node = props.node
  return <Node id="123" />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

A `React.FunctionComponent` is typed as:

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

They key bit there is:

```
(props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
```

So `ReactElement` is the the return type of a functional component. All `ReactElement` means is that it's rendered JSX. `<>foo</>` is a `ReactElement`, and so is `<div>I'm a div</div>`.

What JSX is rendered by a component is just not part of its static type.